# Javascript function for simple slider not executing onclick

Tags: javascript, function, slide

Hello and thanks for looking up.
I have decided to learn Javascript by trial and error and Googling the stuff that I need. So far so good, but when I tried something a bit tricky, a slider, things got tough.

I dont really have good knowledge about syntax in Javascript and how expressions should be written in functions but I am trying.

So here we have a simple 4 images in a div with 2 arrows slider. When we click the arrow we want the counter to decrease by 1, we want to be sure it doesnt equal 0 and if it does we change it to 4, and when this is done we give the respective image ( img[counter] ) a z index of 50 for example. But it doesnt work. For some reason.

Here is a fiddle of the whole thing and hope I dont trouble  you guys too much with this.

https://jsfiddle.net/wu2Lysrv/3/

```
function slideEngine() {
    var img1 = document.querySelector("#img1");
    var img2 = document.querySelector("#img2");
    var img3 = document.querySelector("#img3");
    var img4 = document.querySelector("#img4");
    var counter = 1;

    function slideL() {
        counter--;
        if (counter == 0) {
            counter = 4;
        }
        img[counter].setAttribute("z-index", "50");
    }
}
```

I would understand if someone goes aggro, since I bet this piece of code over there is very very wrong. Still I would like to learn how do I do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `slideL` function lives inside `slideEngine`, so your html doesn't have direct access to it.

One potential fix is to simply remove the wrapping function, since it doesn't seem to be used anywhere. However, there are other issues with the code that will prevent it from working. I've attempted to fix some below.

```
var img1 = document.querySelector("#img1");
var img2 = document.querySelector("#img2");
var img3 = document.querySelector("#img3");
var img4 = document.querySelector("#img4");
var counter = 1;

function slideL() {
    counter--;
    if (counter == 0) {
        counter = 4;
    }
    window['img'+counter].style.zIndex = 50;
}
```

I didn't tes this, but try it out.

Comment: Nope, still doesnt quite do it.... :/ what is the Window for ? it addresses elements that are currently displayed?

Comment: I just tested this. It does solve the issue the question is about, but the logic is wrong and/or not complete. Because I removed the `slideEngine` function, your `img*` variable re now in the global scope. To access them by constructing their name as a string, you need to find them on their parent, which is `window`. It has nothing to do with whether they are currently displayed.

Comment: I copy pasted this on the jsfiddle and it didnt work ?

Comment: UPDATE: Ended up still using Z index for changing slides for now, and it works thanks to your suggestion for the window['img'+counter].style.zIndex = ... so I would like to thank you :)